# log rotation script for logstash to purge logs greater than two weeks old

Tags: logstash

I'm trying to come up with the best way to purge the logs from a logstash server that are more than two weeks old.

For those that aren't aware, Logstash stores it's logs inside of Elasticsearch. We have a really great stable ELK stack (Elasticsearch/Logstash/Kibana) where I work.

The typical way of deleting a logstash index is with a curl command like this one:

```
#curl --user admin -XDELETE http://localhost:9200/logstash-2015.06.06
Enter host password for user 'admin':
{"acknowledged":true}
```

Now what I'm looking for is a programmatic way of changing the dates in the logstash index to automatically purge any index that's greater than two weeks old.

I'm thinking of using bash to get this done.

I'd appreciate any examples of how to do this or advice you may have!

Thanks

Thanks!! But do you think you can help me get this going using auth?

This is what I tried so far:

```
[root@logs:~] #curator --help | grep -i auth
  --http_auth TEXT   Use Basic Authentication ex: user:pass
[root@logs:~] #curator delete indices --older-than 14 --time-unit days --timestring %Y.%m.%d --regex '^logstash-' --http_auth admin:secretsauce
Error: no such option: --http_auth
[root@logs:~] #curator delete indices --older-than 14 --time-unit days --timestring %Y.%m.%d --regex '^logstash-' --http_auth admin:secretsauce
Error: no such option: --http_auth
[root@logs:~] #curator delete indices --http_auth admin:secretsauce --older-than 14 --time-unit days --timestring %Y.%m.%d --regex '^logstash-'
Error: no such option: --http_auth
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [Curator](https://github.com/elastic/curator). To delete indexes older than 14 days you can run this command:

```
curator delete indices --older-than 14 --time-unit days --timestring %Y.%m.%d --regex '^logstash-'
```

Comment: Thanks Magnus! I appreciate the help! But I have one more question that didn't fit in the comments. Can you take a look?

I get more and more impressed with elastic stuff every day! Nice little tool!

Comment: This is really a different question, but I suspect the problem is that `--http_auth` is an option to the curator command rather than its delete indices subcommand, i.e. you should run `curator --http_auth ... delete indices --older-than ...`.

Comment: Yup! That was it. 

#curator --http_auth admin:secretsauce delete indices --older-than 14 --time-unit days --timestring %Y.%m.%d --regex '^logstash-'

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

If curator doesn't work for you for one reason or another, here's a bash script you can run:

```
#!/bin/bash

: ${2?"Usage: $0 [number of days] [base url of elastic]"}

days=${1}
baseURL=${2}

curl "${baseURL}/_cat/indices?v&h=i" | grep logstash | sort --key=1 | awk -v n=${days} '{if(NR>n) print a[NR%n]; a[NR%n]=$0}' | awk -v baseURL="$baseURL" '{printf "curl -XDELETE '\''%s/%s'\''\n", baseURL, $1}' | while read x ; do eval $x ; done
```

Comment: it works, except that need to replace XGET with XDELETE

Answer (score 1):

The [online documentation for Curator](http://elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current) explains many of these details.  The URL is handily provided at the top of the --help output:

```
$ curator --help
Usage: curator [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

  Curator for Elasticsearch indices.

  See http://elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current
```

[There's an entire sub-section on flags](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/flags.html).  In the [documentation for the --http_auth](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/http_auth.html) flag it says:

> This flag must come before any command.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do it on newer versions (7.x+) of ElasticSearch/OpenSearch is to use state management policies, you can read more about it here https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/automating-index-state-management-for-amazon-opensearch-service-successor-to-amazon-elasticsearch-service/

Here is how to use it to delete old indexes:

```
{
    "policy": {
        "description": "Removes old indexes",
        "default_state": "active",
        "states": [
            {
                "name": "active",
                "transitions": [
                    {
                        "state_name": "delete",
                        "conditions": {
                            "min_index_age": "14d"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "delete",
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "delete": {}
                    }
                ],
                "transitions": []
            }
        ],
        "ism_template": {
            "index_patterns": [
                "mylogs-*"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

It will automatically apply the policy for any new `mylogs-*` indexes, but you'll need to apply it manually for existing ones (under "Index Management" -> "Indices").

Comment: Policies can also be set via the api with a PUT request i.e.
```curl -X PUT "<your cluster url>/_opendistro/_ism/policies/del1?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "policy": {
  ...
}'
```
for v6.8+

Answer (score 0):

The ElasticSearch X-Pack lets you set a policy to automatically delete indexes based on age. This is a fairly complex solution, and also paid for: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-lifecycle-management.html

Curator seems to be well maintained, supports recent versions of ElasticSearch and does what you want.

Alternatively, here's a BASH script. However, it won't work on BSD or Mac, because of my use of non-POSIX `date -ud`.

I use systemd to run this daily.

```
    #!/usr/bin/env bash 

    elasticsearchURL="http://localhost:9200"
    date_format="%Y.%m.%d"
    today_seconds=$(date +"%s")
    let seconds_per_day=24*60*60
    let delay_seconds=$seconds_per_day*7
    let cutoff_seconds=$today_seconds-$delay_seconds
    cutoff_date=$(date -ud "@$cutoff_seconds" +"$date_format")
    indices=$(curl -XGET "${elasticsearchURL}/_cat/indices" | cut -d ' ' -f 3 | grep -P "\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}")

    echo "Deleting indexes created before the cutoff date $cutoff_date."

    for index in $indices; do
        index_date=$(echo "$index" | grep -P --only-matching "\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}")
        if [[ $index_date < $cutoff_date ]]; then
            echo "Deleting old index $index"
            curl -XDELETE "${elasticsearchURL}/$index"
            echo ""
        fi
    done
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this, there is a special utility ["Curator" from Elastic](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/index.html). It must be installed as [specified in the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/installation.html).

Then you need to write the address to ElasticSerach server in the "hosts" parameter in [the configuration File](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/5.0/configfile.html). On Windows, this file should be located in the user folder, for example: c:\Users\yourUserName\.curator\curator.yml

Then you need by [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/index.html) create a file with the actions "curatorRotateLogs.yml", for example, such:

```
---
# Remember, leave a key empty if there is no value.  None will be a string,
# not a Python "NoneType"
actions:
  1:
    action: delete_indices
    description: >-
      Delete indices older than 45 days (based on index name), for logstash-
      prefixed indices. Ignore the error if the filter does not result in an
      actionable list of indices (ignore_empty_list) and exit cleanly.
    options:
      ignore_empty_list: True
      disable_action: False
    filters:
    - filtertype: pattern
      kind: prefix
      value: logstash-
    - filtertype: age
      source: name
      direction: older
      timestring: '%Y.%m.%d'
      unit: days
      unit_count: 14
```

Then run through the scheduler: "C:\Program Files\elasticsearch-curator\curator.exe" c:\MyСoolFolder\curatorRotateLogs.yml