# Without using curator how can I delete or expire indices which are old example in my case 30 days older indices need to be deleted automatically

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration, ttl, elasticsearch-2.0

I want to delete all logs which are 30 days older from today example logstash filename is below

```
logstash-2016-11-30
```

is there any configuration to which I can set a value by which automatically it will remove old data.

and which is the better option configuration (*.yml) files or firing a query.

Comment: This is the perfect job for the [curator tool](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/ex_delete_indices.html). Check it out.

Comment: If you are using a crontab to launch curator and if you are using the timestring option when launching curator, don't forget that % are considered line break for crontab and have to be escaped like this \% ([cf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16238460/why-percent-signs-do-not-work-in-crontab))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [log rotation script for logstash to purge logs greater than two weeks old](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31421143/log-rotation-script-for-logstash-to-purge-logs-greater-than-two-weeks-old)

Comment: You can check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31421143/log-rotation-script-for-logstash-to-purge-logs-greater-than-two-weeks-old/) for answers

Comment: is there any example to use ttl with index during creation of index or through config file and where to write the ttl in config file, 
The reason I am looking for this approach is my logstash is not that much big which needs curator tool

Comment: Mr. A, TTL is deprecated in Elasticsearch 2.x, and removed in Elasticsearch 5.0.  You must either manage at the index level, or use the delete_by_query plugin.

Answer (score 2):

For Curator  4.1.2, you can use the next line on crontab:

```
00 00 * * * curator --config /etc/logstash/curator/curator.yml /etc/logstash/curator/delete
```

Where /etc/logstash/curator/curator.yml is like

```
    # Remember, leave a key empty if there is no value.  None will be a string,
# not a Python "NoneType"
client:
  hosts:
   - 127.0.0.1
  port: 9200
  url_prefix:
  use_ssl: False
  certificate:
  client_cert:
  client_key:
  aws_key:
  aws_secret_key:
  aws_region:
  ssl_no_validate: False
  http_auth:
  timeout: 30
  master_only: False

logging:
  loglevel: INFO
  logfile:
  logformat: default
  blacklist: ['elasticsearch', 'urllib3']
```

and /etc/logstash/curator/delete is like:

```
    # Remember, leave a key empty if there is no value.  None will be a string,
# not a Python "NoneType"
#
# Also remember that all examples have 'disable_action' set to True.  If you
# want to use this action as a template, be sure to set this to False after
# copying it.
actions:
  1:
  action: delete_indices
  description: >-
  #Delete older than 30 days
  options:
    ignore_empty_list: True
    timeout_override:
    continue_if_exception: False
    disable_action: False #True
  filters:
  - filtertype: pattern
    kind: prefix
    value: logstash-
    exclude:
  - filtertype: age
    source: creation_date
    direction: older
    unit: days
    unit_count: 30
    exclude:
```

You can create new actions and use other "age" filters like seconds, minutes...

Answer (score 0):

Curator 4.2.3 re-introduced the command-line singleton as existed in Curator 3.x.  You can read more [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/singleton-cli.html).

```
curator_cli [ARGS] delete-indices --filter_list '...'
```

Comment: Yes.  It's under an Apache 2.0 license.

Comment: $ curator_cli curator_cli: command not found but $ curator
Usage: curator [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

  Curator for Elasticsearch indices.

  See http://elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current

How can I install it ?

Comment: You're probably installed an older version of curator.  Don't just install what comes in the repository for your OS.  Elastic provides its own repositories at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/installation.html