# How to delete old logs in elacticsearch came from logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I use elk stack. Logs are collected in indices in elasticsearch in follwing format:
logname_yyyy-mm-dd

I want to delete old logs automatically somehow. Say I want to delete all indices which are older then two weeks.

What is the best way to do than automatically?

Comment: I'd suggest using the curator tool for this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/ex_delete_indices.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [log rotation script for logstash to purge logs greater than two weeks old](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31421143/log-rotation-script-for-logstash-to-purge-logs-greater-than-two-weeks-old)