# AWS elasticsearch log rotation

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I want to use AWS elasticsearch to store the log of my application. Since there a huge amount of data to input to AWS elasticsearch ( ~30GB daily), so i would only keep 3 days of data. Are there any way to schedule data removal from AWS elasticsearch or do a log rotation? What happen if the AWS elasticsearch storage is full?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

A possible way is to specify the *index* parameter in `elasticsearch`*output* to something like **logstash-%{appname}-%{date_format}"**. Hence you can then use [curator plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/ex_delete_indices.html#ex_delete_indices) in order to delete the old indices by number of days or so.

This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31421143/log-rotation-script-for-logstash-to-purge-logs-greater-than-two-weeks-old) pretty much explains the same. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the AWS Amazon Elasticsearch Service?

The storage type is an EBS volume with a fixed size of disk space. If you want to keep only the last three days, I assume you have 3 indices then, like that

```
my-index-2017.01.30
my-index-2017.01.31
my-index-2017.02.01
```

Basically you can write some simple script which deletes indices older than 3 days. With the REST API it just is in Sense `DELETE my-index-2017.01.30`.

I recommend to use Elasticsearch Curator for the job. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/delete_indices.html

I'm not sure if the Service interface itself has an option for that. But Elasticsearch Curator should do the job for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, AWS ES does not yet provide the necessary data in the `/_cluster/state` endpoint for Curator to work with it.  See https://github.com/elastic/curator/issues/880

Answer (score 0):

Update for 2020:

AWS ES has now support for Index state management which lets you define custom management policies to automate routine tasks and apply them to indices and index patterns. You no longer need to set up and manage external processes to run your index operations.

For example, you can define a policy that moves your index into a read_only state after 30 days and then ultimately deletes it after 90 days.

Index State Management - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/ism.html